# Changing the group to nogroup in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, file-management, file-permissions, chown

I'm trying to change the group of several files in Mac OS X using the group `nogroup`:

```
chown my_user:nogroup file.txt
```

Problem is that it does not change at all, although the nogroup is currently listed in `/etc/group` and Directory Service (I checked it with `dscl . list /groups`).

What can be happening?

**EDIT:**
I wanted to do this because XAMMP user and group is `nobody:nogroup`, and I needed XAMMP's httpd server to be able to write in some directories. I ended up changing the group to `_www`, but curiosity made ask this question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the GID of nogroup is (intentionally) `-1`, which is an illegal GID for chown.

Why do you want to do that?

Comment: However, you can do it with `nobody` group, which is `-2`. That's why I got surprised. I've edited the question to clarify my purpose